# Placing bitmap at various points around a circle results in the bitmap being different distances away from center

Tags: android, math, canvas, bitmap, rotation

I want to place a small triangular bitmap centered on the dotted circle as similar to as follows:

[image]

Here is my code that places the bitmap according to a specified angle:

```
    x = (float) (center.x + radius* Math.cos(Math.toRadians(getRotationAngle())));

    y = (float) (center.y + radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(getRotationAngle())));

    canvas.drawBitmap(mCurrentTimeIndicatorBitmap, x, y, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));
```

`getRotationAngle()` returns a value between 0 and 360 (inclusive). `center.x`, `center.y` are a constant `500` and radius is a constant `313.3`. However, as I rotate around the circle, the bitmap's distance to the dotted line varies and I do not know why. The above picture is with rotation angle at 0, where it is farthest from the center.

Near rotation angle 90:

[image]

Near rotation angle 180, where it is the furthest from the dotted line & closest to the center:

[image]

Near rotation angle 270:

[image]

As you can see the triangle is various distances away from the dotted line. What is causing this? My code to draw the dotted lines is very similar but no issue occurs there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you draw bitmap, you are using left top corner as base point. So this corner walks around the circle exactly. But bitmap center moves along the circle that is shifted to right and bottom.

Just subtract half-size of bitmap to get corner coordinates at every step (or shift center coordinates)

```
x = (float) (center.x  - mCurrentTimeIndicatorBitmap.width / 2 + 
            radius* Math.cos(Math.toRadians(getRotationAngle())));

y = (float) (center.y - mCurrentTimeIndicatorBitmap.height / 2 + 
             radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(getRotationAngle())));

canvas.drawBitmap(mCurrentTimeIndicatorBitmap, x, y, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));
```